# How can I see, if an answer is accepted or not?

Tags: support, accepted-answer

This is particularly related to SO questions. How can I verify whether an answer of the question is accepted or not?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a tick mark left to the answer

Comment: if right tick is not available there than?

Comment: @mahesh If a particular question do not have any tick mark to the left of the answer, then still no answer is accepted as correct answer

Answer (score 0):

In the index where you view the list of questions, the 2nd square mentioning the number of answers (between votes and views), has a green tinge to it. I guess its standard on all SO sites.